# Whenever I'm using meta_key in my custom queries I don't get expected results

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using the custom query on the event post type, I'm using advance custom field plugin and 'event_date' is my field group name. I want to sort the events according to the event date. Here is code for reference.

```
 $homepageEvents = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
      ));
```

But whenever I use meta_key => 'event_date' it returns only 2 result and I've 3 events. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm that all three CPTs have that field set?

Comment: I think I got it, I've done like this  'meta_key' => get_field('event_date'),

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/ review the advanced examples

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I figured out that I didn't set that field in one of my event. That's why it shows unexpected behavior. "'meta_key' => get_field('event_date'), " This code is wrong way to do this.